# MySQL: A query that finds active customers in the database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I need help figuring out which query to run to search for a customer. I'm building a "money loaning" program which has a search functionality. The user can filter the customers displayed in the system through customerFirstName, customerSecondName, and whether or not they're active.

The thing is, there is no `status` column in the customer table. A costumer is considered **Active** if one or more of their accounts have status = 'Active'.
A customer is considered **Inactive** if they have not opened any accounts OR all their accounts have status = 'Paid'

My SELECT statement is:

```
SELECT 
customer.customerID,
customerFName,
customerLName,
gender,
civilStatus,
birthDate,
homeAddress,
jobDescription,
workingAddress,
telNumber,
phoneNumber,
pinNumber
```

A customer is filtered by first and last names through this condition:

```
WHERE customerFName LIKE '%*userProvidedFirstName*%' AND customerLName LIKE '%*userProvidedLastName*%'
```

This is my database schema:

[image: This is my database ERD]

Comment: Is it safe to assume that if the customer has no `Active` accounts, the customer s `Inactive`?

Comment: @VitaliiStrimbanu yes :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try getting the status in the select portion and then filtering based on a sub select:

```
select * from
    (SELECT 
    customer.customerID,
    customerFName,
    customerLName,
    gender,
    civilStatus,
    birthDate,
    homeAddress,
    jobDescription,
    workingAddress,
    telNumber,
    phoneNumber,
    pinNumber
    case when (select count(*) from account where account.customerID = customerID and account.status = 'Active') > 0 
    then 'Active' else 'Inactive' end as status
from customer)
    WHERE customerFName LIKE '%*userProvidedFirstName*%' AND customerLName LIKE '%*userProvidedLastName*%' AND status = *Status*
```